# Problema de array

Tags: javascript, array, navegador-web, calculo

estoy intentando hacer una calculadora y tengo un problema y es que el segundo numero con el que intento sumar el primer numero sale undefined y no se porque.

```
let operation = prompt('Escribe la operación matematica');
let operation_out_of_phase = operation.split(" ");

let actualResult = 0;

for (dato in operation_out_of_phase) {
    if (operation_out_of_phase[dato] == "+") {
        console.log(operation_out_of_phase[dato-1], operation_out_of_phase[dato], operation_out_of_phase[dato+1])
    }
}

console.log(operation_out_of_phase);
```

el `operation_out_of_phase[dato+1]` siempre me sale undefined. (Se debe introducir en el prompt por ejemplo `1 + 2` con los espacios)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tu problema es que `for ... in` itera **sobre el contenido** del *array*, no **sobre el índice**. Y tu código necesita esto último para funcionar:

```js
let operation = prompt('Escribe la operación matematica');
let operation_out_of_phase = operation.split(" ");

let actualResult = 0;

for( let idx = 0; idx < operation_out_of_phase.length; ++idx ) {
    if( operation_out_of_phase[idx] == "+" ) {
        console.log( operation_out_of_phase[idx - 1], operation_out_of_phase[idx], operation_out_of_phase[idx + 1] )
    }
}

console.log( operation_out_of_phase );
```